# why is this simple bash trap failing

Tags: bash, bash-trap, shell-trap

I'm still pretty new to bash scripting, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why this simple trap is not working as expected.

**Goal** - create an optional waiting period that can be skipped by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

**Expected result of pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** - immediately echo "No time for napping!" and exit.

**Actual result of pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** - immediately echo "naptime over." and exit.

```
#!/bin/bash

nonap() {
    echo "No time for napping!"
    exit
}

trap nonap INT

echo "Sleeping for 5 seconds, hit ctrl-c to proceed now."
sleep 5 
echo "Naptime over."
```

Why is my trap function not invoked?

Comment: This works fine for me. What's your environment?

Comment: I just tried it (on ancient Linux with bash 3.2.25) and saved your code in `trap.sh`, ran `bash trap.sh`, and got: `Sleeping for 5 seconds, hit ctrl-c to proceed now.` followed by `No time for napping!` when I interrupted, as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  At least I know it *should* work as expected. I'm using the latest version of Tinycore Linux with GNU bash, version 4.0.33(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu).  Upon opening a new terminal, declare -f nonap and trap both return no output.  After running this script and getting the "Naptime over." output, `trap` returns `trap -- 'nonap' SIGINT` and `declare -f nonap` returns the function as defined in my script.

Comment: How are you running this script, then?  Using `source` or `.` to read it?  Ah, yes; you must be.  I just tried that, and the interrupt while sourcing gave me `Naptime over.`; typing another interrupt though gave me `No time for napping!` and the shell exited.  The second time it behaved as expected; I'm not sure what's up with the interrupt while dotting the script.  That is unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Why did you want to source or dot this?  Why not just use it as a plain old script?

Comment: No reason to source...I was just using that to run it while testing.  I guess I've never run into any anomalies like this when using . before, but I'm still a newb too.  I am seeing the same results you are, and it works as expected on the first interrupt if I run it with bash.   Thanks for figuring that out.  It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it (on an ancient RHEL Linux with bash 3.2.25) and saved your code in `trap.sh`, ran `bash trap.sh`, and got:

```
 Sleeping for 5 seconds, hit ctrl-c to proceed now.
```

followed by:

```
No time for napping!
```

when I interrupted, as you expected.  When I let it run without interrupting, I got the expected message:

```
Naptime over.
```

You then commented:

> At least I know it *should* work as expected. I'm using the latest version of Tinycore Linux with GNU bash, version 4.0.33(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu). Upon opening a new terminal, `declare -f nonap` and `trap` both return no output. After running this script and getting the "Naptime over." output, `trap` returns `trap -- 'nonap' SIGINT` and `declare -f nonap` returns the function as defined in my script.

To which I responded:

How are you running this script, then? Using `source` or `.` to read it? Ah, yes; you must be. I just tried that, and the interrupt while sourcing gave me `Naptime over.`; typing another interrupt though gave me `No time for napping!` and the shell exited. The second time it behaved as expected; I'm not sure what's up with the interrupt while dotting the script. That is unexpected behaviour.

Why did you want to source or dot this? Why not just use it as a plain old script?

> No reason to source...I was just using that to run it while testing. I guess I've never run into any anomalies like this when using . before, but I'm still a newb too. I am seeing the same results you are, and it works as expected on the first interrupt if I run it with bash.

Well, there's a "Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when I hit my head against the wall" component to the following advice, but there's also basic pragmatism in there too.

You use `source` (in C shell or `bash`) or `.` (in Bourne, Korn, POSIX shells or `bash`) to have the script affect the environment of the invoking shell, rather than running as a sub-shell.  The giveaway to solving the problem (albeit largely by fluke) was when you reported that after running the script, you had the function defined; that can't happen unless you were using `source`.  In this case, it is fairly clear that you do not want the `trap` set in the calling shell.  When I ran it (from a `ksh` with prompt `Toru JL:`), I got:

```
Toru JL: bash
bash-3.2$ trap
bash-3.2$ source trap.sh
Sleeping for 5 seconds, hit ctrl-c to proceed now.

Naptime over.
bash-3.2$ trap
trap -- 'nonap' INT
bash-3.2$ No time for napping!
Toru JL:
```

The 'No time for napping!' message appeared when I hit the interrupt key again, and it terminated the `bash` I'd run.  If you continue to use it with `source`, you would want to add `trap INT` to the end of the script, and you might also want to undefine the the function.

However, you are much better off isolating it all in a shell and running it as a sub-process, I think.

But...your finding that this sort of thing plays funny games when the script is sourced is interesting.  It's a minor anomaly in the behaviour of `bash`.  I'm not sure it rises to the level of 'bug'; I'd have to read a lot of manual rather carefully (probably several times) and consult with other knowledgeable people before claiming 'bug'.

I'm not sure it will be any consolation, but I tried `ksh` on your script with `.` and it worked as we'd both expect:

```
Toru JL: ksh
$ . trap.sh
Sleeping for 5 seconds, hit ctrl-c to proceed now.
No time for napping!
Toru JL:
```

Comment: Thanks again for the thoughtful responses.  I was reviewing source/. after you figured out that was causing the problem.  From what I could gather, sounds like you're dead on.  I'm not convinced it's a "bug" either...maybe just a nuanced reason that I'm not fully grasping.

Comment: I will be running all my scripts WITHOUT source from now on unless I have a good reason to do so. So, you solved my immediate problem and taught me a good lesson about invoking scripts in the process.  Thanks again!